# Show that $f(x)$ has no repeated roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x)= \frac{x^n}{n!} +\frac{x^{(n-1)}}{(n−1)!}+···+x+1$,then show that $f(x)=0$ has no repeated roots.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 8):

On the contrary if $\alpha$ was a repeated root, then $f(\alpha) = f'(\alpha) = 0$

Subtracting the above two equations tells you something about $\alpha$. Now can such an alpha be a root?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the derivative of a polynomial is zero at a root of that polynomial [if that root is repeated](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/RepeatRootPoly/RepeatedRoots.html).  Now use induction on $n$.